# Ошибка "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.UI.Text[]' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'" при добавлении в Text[] через цикл GetComponent<Text>()>

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, циклы

Есть массив объектов с текстом, который надо редактировать несколько раз, поэтому решил сохранить в массив `Text[]` (пробовал и через `List<Text>`), но выдает ошибку: "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.UI.Text[]' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text*'". Подскажете в чем проблема? (Через `[SerializeField]` конечно работает, но хотелось бы кодом).

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject[] plates;
private Text[] textPlate;
for(int i = 0; i < plates.Length; i++) textPlate[i] = plates[i].GetComponent<Text>();
```

Comment: проблема за пределами показанного кода, в вырезанном фрагменте указанной ошибки нет.

Comment: прикол в том, что это первое действие и unity указывает именно на эту строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что ты не инициализировал массив `textPlate`. Когда ты создаёшь массив, ты должен указать его размер. Кроме того, код должен быть в методе или функции. В данном случае, это может быть метод `Start()` или `Awake()`:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject[] plates;
private Text[] textPlate;

void Start() {
    textPlate = new Text[plates.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < plates.Length; i++) textPlate[i] = plates[i].GetComponent<Text>();
}
```

Вызывать `GetComponent<Text>()` для `GameObject` не всегда будет возвращать компонент `Text`, если на `GameObject` не настроен такой компонент. Если ты уверен, что каждый `GameObject` имеет компонент `Text`, тогда код должен работать. В противном случае, добавь проверку на `null`.

Также, убедись, что используешь пространство имен `UnityEngine.UI` для класса `Text`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Comment: 1. Не инициализировал массив. 2. ошибка связана с GetComponentsInChildren. Он ищет несколько элементов, поэтому получается массив массивов. Нужно использовать GetComponentInChildren (без s)

Comment: Это самый ужасный метод реализации. Нужно постараться, чтобы такое придумать. 1. Получение компонента (Это нагрузка как попытка его поиска) 2. Проверка на null (много кода и лишняя нагрузка) 3. Лишние ссылки на компоненты (большая востребованность в памяти) Вы не разработчик и даже не любить, хуже... Причем намного

Answer (score 0):

```
internal sealed class UpdateText
{
    [SerializeField] private Text[] _texts;

    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < _texts.Length; iterator++)
            _texts[iterator].text = $"{iterator}";
    }
}
```

Рекомендую воспользоваться не `GameObject` а сразу компонентом `Text`. Так мы избавимся от лишних итераций попытки получения компонентов, копирования и аллоцирование лишних объемов памяти, для хранения ссылок.